# What would happen if I faked the amount of packets coming through using tcp

Tags: networking, tcp

Let's say I am creating a faulty tcp server that says for example to another
 computer that 7 packets will be coming through but only 6 are sent. 
 
What would the other computer do?

Comment: You can't do this, because there's nothing in the protocol that says "x packets will be coming through". Either you send x packets, or you don't.

Comment: But then how can you be sure that those packets came through?, isn't that the whole point of tcp?

Comment: "But then how can you be sure that those packets came through?, " - You **can't** at least not with TCP

Comment: @Slipknot1, the receiver doesn't know the number of packets to be received, but it sends an ACKs for received data. The sender needs to recognize when data is not ACKed and retransmit the data.

Answer (score 1):

The TCP protocol itself never specifies how many packets are supposed to be transferred from the server to the client. The client merely sends ACK (acknowledgement) packets back to the server whenever it receives a TCP packet. The protocol is designed with faulty networks in mind, so a server failing to send another packet won't cause any harm.

Now, on the *application layer*, you can write a piece of software that expects a previously communicated number of bytes (such as a download manager) and having a faulty server would indeed cause it to malfunction. But that's outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how or if the connection was shut down. If you're referring to a system crash and the sender simply stops transmitting this article will help explain keepalives if they are in use. Keepalives are not required by TCP.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html